# Показатели видео, чем кодируются в ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

Есть информация о видео на выходе:
`Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 16 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc"`
Мне удалось найти ключи до битрейта, остальные меняются в зависимости от видео.

Что значат все остальные, какими ключами их кодировать?:
`25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc`

Answer (score 1):

`-r` - fps. Всё остальное - диагностика, и вам не особо нужно менять. Что такое, тут: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3199489/meaning-of-ffmpeg-output-tbc-tbn-tbr